Do utilities ever disconnect solar panels in cases of low demand?
This question asked something that was predicated on "solar roof installations [being] disconnected from [the] grid" for low demand.
Do utilities ever disconnect solar installations for low demand?  I would expect that when the brightest sun occurs, that would be when the most demand would occur so they would leave solar installations connected as long as there is power.  If there is a problem say, if power lines are down, and work needs to be done, obviously, the solar installations would be disconnected but under normal conditions, is there ever a case where utilities need to shed solar generation?

Unless you stop the sun, there is energy.  If you have a tracker, you can use it and energy to reduce your direct surface area. Any action will incur wear, whether its shutting and restarting a gas turbine or letting excess energy heat the panels. Ideally no change is needed and demand perfectly matches supply, but that is never the case. Priority goes to storage when excess is available.

Even with off grid installations, pv panels get left open circuit when batteries are fully charged, so no problem with pv to be left in a grid connected case

Yes there is, and here's a news item about it.  Note that they can't do this with a traditional domestic solar installation as it would also cut all power to the house (well they can but I'm not sure how they'd spin it). The network operator needs a remote control switch to isolate the panels from the grid https://www.abc.net.au/news/2021-03-17/solar-panels-switched-off-in-sa-to-stabilise-grid/13256572

@GregLocock  Thanks for the link.  That answers the question.  In my area of the US, if you want to sell solar power to the utility, you have to get a goofy smart meter that measures power coming in and power going out.  I believe it is addressable by the utility so they could turn off your feed to their grid if they felt they did not have enough rotating power being generated.

What utility? In all likelihood they don't need that meter and can't actually use it to control anything. Many utilities in the U.S. don't want the hassle of dealing with more solar on their grids so they throw up expensive roadblocks in the name of "safety", such as separate metering requirements. Standards for inverters automatically reduce output during overvoltage (a sign of low demand). All newer inverters do this automatically, and older inverters can typically do it with a free firmware upgrade. I'll write a full answer when I've got some time.

First, I work for an electrical company in Europe, and specifically for the department that handles energy optimization and dispatching in an european island of medium size.
I know electrical systems pretty well and the workings of productions that inject in the low/medium voltage grids (namely photovoltaic).
The situation varies for very small installation on the low voltage network (roof 3 to 30 kW) , medium ones in the LV low voltage network (30 to 250 kW) and the big ones in the MV medium or HV high voltage grid (> 300 kW).
All modern inverters may be connected to the internet (or VPN networks) and can be dispatched, that is power can be limited to zero without phisical disconnection from the network. That is not technically a problem for PV.
In small and medium installations the power can not be modulated, that is only left to maximum MPPT or "limited to zero"
In big MV/HV installations you can also tell the installation to reduce its power, for instance to 50% of maximum power.
Utilities is not the correct term, instead we will talk about TSO (transmission system operator) or DSO (distribution system operator).
In big systems DSO (like networks of US, Europe and so on) will mainly  make disconnect medium, high voltage PV plants for security reasons, if work on MV HV lines need to be carried out and safety of personnel ensured.
In smaller electrical systems TSO do limit the instant part of photovoltaic (mainly piloting big installations) if they represent too big a part of load. That is because PV/Wind plants are not stable, and do not provide ancillary services to the network, they lack inertia, frequency regulation,etc..
That is why, for now, you need to maintain some rotating machines (hydro, coal, gas, nuclear...) to stabilize the AC electricl system, and thus limit the part of plants interfaced with power electronics (PV, Wind).
Another mechanism that regularly limits PV or Wind Farms productions (in continental europe, and probably other countires) are electricity markets.
In europe, there are reguarly negative prices for some hours a day.
Big powerplants (ex. coal) do not like to shut off for some hours a day (ex PV peak when the offer of energy on the market is too abundant for the load).
These actors on the market will pay through the market other producers (like PV and Wind Farms) to limit their production (they will gain money through negative prices) and let powerplants stay on.
Finally, there are also some other security constraints on big networks where TSO will limit production and will compensate economically (ex wind farms in england or germany)

I'll say that pretty solidly answered the question.  The plant I worked at was a base load station that just ran 100% all the time but the utility had "spinning reserve" (I think they called it), coal plants that were running with minimum output so they could quickly pick up and feed the grid if necessary. Before this discussion, I had never thought about turning down PV and wind farms.  What do you know?
